# How do I increase the size of EditText dynamically in android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-edittext

I want the height of EditText to be increased dynamically as per the size of text inputted.

Just like Whatsapp.

Here is what i am doing now!

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="44dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <EditText
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:hint="Enter New Note"
        android:textColorHint="#8B111111"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="Enter Input Here"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/editextNew"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: just get in acitvity and give width/hieight to it that  :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand @ParthPitroda

Comment: change the height to wrap content and add max lines to the number of lines you want.

Comment: the size of EditText becomes very small after this at start! @RituSumanMohanty

Comment: Add min lines to 5 or 10

Comment: Still same @RituSumanMohanty

Comment: Your `LinearLayout` still has height of 44dp.

Answer (score 3):

Please try this :

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <EditText
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:hint="Enter New Note"
        android:maxLines="40"
        android:lines="20"
        android:textColorHint="#8B111111"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="Enter Input Here"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:id="@+id/editextNew"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only change you have to make (both occurrence):
`android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Answer (score 0):

Because you're giving it a fixed_height. Change that to wrap_content and it should work.

You can add android:maxLines to limit how much it expands.